# How to uninstall MonoTouch framework?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I would like to be able to uninstall monotouch framework from my Mac OS X, but I don't see a way to do so...

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete `/Developer/MonoTouch`

Comment: After removing that folder, you may also want to run this command at the command-line: sudo pkgutil --forget com.novell.monotouch.pkg

Answer (score 16):

Easy to go just 2 steps:

```
sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoTouch
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.monotouch.pkg
```

[Source](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/160675-how-do-i-uninstall-monotouch-)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the other answers if you may want to delete other xamarin packages installed, enter:

```
pkgutil --packages
```

and look for all com.xamarin packages and remove them via:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.[name of the package]
```