# MonoTouch build failed due to resgen error

Tags: xamarin.ios, resgen

I get the following error when MonoTouch runs resgen on a .resx file in the solution:

```
strings.resx: Error: 
Native stacktrace:

* Assertion at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:1778, condition `class' not met

0   mono                                0x000d533a mono + 869178
1   mono                                0x001385ba mono + 1275322
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9ba2e59b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9b9c9c0c abort + 214
5   mono                                0x00282811 mono + 2627601
6   mono                                0x00282873 mono + 2627699
7   mono                                0x001eb432 mono + 2008114
8   mono                                0x001eb3f3 mono + 2008051
9   mono                                0x001df6fa mono + 1959674
10  mono                                0x001df7fd mono + 1959933
11  mono                                0x0022810a mono + 2257162
12  mono                                0x0022857d mono + 2258301
13  mono                                0x00139160 mono + 1278304
14  mono                                0x000117c7 mono + 67527
15  mono                                0x000a7f0c mono + 683788
16  mono                                0x00002742 mono + 5954
17  mono                                0x000027a1 mono + 6049
18  mono                                0x00002521 mono + 5409

Debug info from gdb:

No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Breakpoint 1 (-[NSException raise]) pending.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Breakpoint 2 (-[_NSZombie release]) pending.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Breakpoint 3 (szone_error) pending.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Breakpoint 4 (objc_exception_throw) pending.
/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.vNC9Gq:1: Error in sourced command file:
unable to debug self
```

I get the same error if I run resgen from Terminal on one of the strings.resx files in the solution. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: You should add a bug report at bugzilla.xamarin.com for this one with a reproducible test case (your resgen commandline with required files), this is most definitively a mono bug.

Comment: I have teammates with the exact same files that don't get the error.

Comment: Do you have the same mono version?

Comment: Yes. Same mono version. Same version of MonoDevelop and same version of MonoTouch.

Comment: I've got it fixed. I'll post my answer when it allows me to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling MonoTouch following the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433589/how-to-uninstall-monotouch-framework) and then reinstalling and that has resolved my issue.

I had tried reinstalling MonoTouch over the top, but that didn't fix it. I had to uninstall and then reinstall.

Comment: How did you reinstall ? did you install the xamarin studio again ?

Comment: Hi @DuraiAmuthan.H, this was 5 1/2 years ago. I don't believe Xamarin Studio existed at that point. Are you getting a similar error?